# Raspberry Pi, how to use push button to start the sensor output, i.e button1 for sensor1, button 2 for sensor2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

How to use push button to start the sensor output continues and stop when i click again.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Button to GPIO23

try:
    while True:
         button1 = GPIO.input(23)
         if button1 == False:
             output = analogInput(0) # Reading from CH0
             print(Output_sensor1)
             time.sleep(0.2)
except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interrupts to toggle a flag when you press the button. Please take a look at this untested example:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

Enable = False

# Callback for interrupt
def ButtonISR(Channel):

  global Enable
  Enable = not Enable

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Use interrupts to detect the button state
GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback = ButtonISR, bouncetime = 200) 

try:
    while True:
      if(Enable):
        output = analogInput(0)
        print(Output_sensor1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

You register a callback (`ButtonISR`) for your GPIO (`23`) with a `bouncetime` of 200 ms (to avoid button bouncing). The `Enable` flag is toggled when you press the button and the sensor output is printed as long as `Enable` stays `True`.

Comment: it sense only one value, and I believe it is continuously sensing or giving output and stop when i push again. I hope somebody can help me.